# In plone 4.2.4, how do I get file and folder size in GUI?

Tags: python, plone

I am using Plone 4.2.4 on linux. I wish to display the size of the uploaded files and the folders created in the site. Is there some addon that can be plugged in easily to display the same in the tabular folder view?

Comment: What you mean as "...and the folders created"? You mean the total size of a folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/681548/keul yes the total size of the folders with the files in it. It should give me an idea of which files I need to delete that occupy more space in zope db

Answer (score 2):

Showing the file is quite easy: you simply need to customize the `folder_tabular_view.pt` adding a new column.
The TAL expression for this should be something like `item/getObjSize`.

---

Size of folders is not that easy because is a complex information: size of a container is the size of objects inside (probably: recursive).

You should override the `getObjSize` catalog metadata for folders (See [plone.indexer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.indexer)) but you must also trigger some event that reindex the whole subtree when some files are changed...

**Can be complex. And slow**.